# Creating a Virtual Host In PHP

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, virtual-hosts

I am trying to set up symfony on my Ubuntu system. Now as going through the installation tutorial of symfony I found to Create a virtual host for my (to be created) application. I did the same steps as bellow.

**httpd.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:9090
Listen 127.0.0.1:9090
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:9090>
ServerName www.symfony.jobeet.lcl
DocumentRoot "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web"
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
Alias /sf /home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
<Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And Here is My **/etc/hosts** file

```
127.0.0.1   www.symfony.jobeet.lcl
```

Now I restarts my lampp server and entered **www.symfony.jobeet.lcl** in my browser it takes me to **http://www.symfony.jobeet.lcl/xampp/** this Url. If I try without using virtual host, It works fine. also when I try **www.symfony.jobeet.lcl:9090** It works. I expect it should work without giving the port number. Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created the simple bash script to simplify the process of new hosts creation. So that you don't have to do anything with config files, etc. Check if you are interested [here](http://dfsq.info/site/read/creating-new-hosts-for-apache2).

Creating new host is as simple as running a command from terminal `$ sudo ./newhost.sh`. Then you will be asked to enter desired host name.

Comment: I am not good at scripting or ubuntu.. Can U xplain me how i can do it. I have copied the script to newhost.sh on my desktop now when i do ./newhosts.sh it says cmd not found

Comment: First of all make sure newhost.sh file is executable. (then run `$ sudo ./newhost.sh`). You will also need to change WWW_ROOT variable to match your username.

Answer (score 1):

Change this lines

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:9090
Listen 127.0.0.1:9090
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:9090>
```

to

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
```

Comment: And What if I want to have 2 Virtual hosts. one on port 8080 and Another on port 9090

Comment: Tried To Do But It Dosent Work as well.. I got the bellow List of Errors
XAMPP: Error 1! Couldn't start Apache!
XAMPP: Starting diagnose...
XAMPP: Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong.
XAMPP: Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/

Comment: It seems that you have a another server/app listening on port 80 already. If you are using Ubuntu, you probably have Apache already installed and running.

Comment: Regarding different ports, you can have as many VirtualHosts as you want on different ports. Check here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost for further details.